# Windows Installer 4.5 for 64 bit

Tags: c#, installshield-2012

How can i install windows installer for 64 bit? I am getting the following error while building the setup file in InstallShield Limited Edition.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling the error it gives in the error list? That's where I would start.

Comment: tried that couldnt find so asked over here...

Comment: You have downloaded the Windows Installer 4.5 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288 ?

Comment: ya i have downloaded the files and when i try to run these files i get the error of Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Comment: Take a look here for a solution: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this/9624b57d-ea4c-41fa-aae0-b52e99b69fab

Comment: I have looked over it and done the necessary changes but cant get my solution...

Comment: Did it actually install for you? If it's not installed, the solution will not build because the files are missing.

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of Windows Installer is currently on the build machine? Does the install require 4.5? If so, why?

Comment: That screenshot is illegible, why not copy the text into your question, where it can be searched?

Answer (score 4):

As for your errors, they can be caused by something as simple as having the directory open in an explorer window (try closing it a rerun). And have a look [at this old IS KB Article](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q107380&sliceId=)

Another possible cause is your Setup PreRequisite file, [see this link](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?147567-setup-prerequisite-generates-meaningless-errors)

"Error appears (in Installshiled 12) if during editing a .prq in Setup Prerequisite Editor select the check-box "Requires Windows Installer engine and/or .NET Framework to be installed first" and after deselect this option. After that in prq-file appears empty section "dependencies", which incorrectly, probably, processed by the builder. It is necessary to remove this section (in any text editor) to avoid an error. "

With regards to your warning:- Have you setup the software id tag ? [the following is taken from here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/SWIDOverview.htm) Especially read the part I've put in bold.

To include a software identification tag in your installation:

- In the View List under Installation Information, click General Information.
- In the Software Identification Tag area of the view, modify the values of the settings as needed.
- The Use Software Identification Tag setting lets you specify whether you want to include a tag in your installation. Select Yes, which is the default value, and then configure the other settings in the Software Identification Tag area as needed.

When you use tagging in your project, InstallShield adds the tag to two new components that it creates, and it associates the components with one of your project’s features. The components are:

- ISO19770_LocalTag, which has a destination of INSTALLDIR
- ISO19770_SystemTag, which has a destination of CommonAppDataFolder

Use the Setup Design view if you want to associate these components with a different feature in your project. For more information, see Component-Feature Associations.

At build time, if the following conditions are true, InstallShield includes the software identification tag with the installation that it builds:

- Yes, the default value, is selected for the Use Software Identification Tag setting in the General Information view.
- The Unique ID, Tag Creator, and Tag Creator ID settings in the General Information view have values.

**Note that if tagging is enabled but you have not entered values in one or more of the three aforementioned tag identification settings, InstallShield generates a build warning to inform you that the tag could not be included in your release. To resolve this warning, configure the settings in the Software Identification Tag area of the General Information view as needed.**

If you configure your project to include a software identification tag and you also configure the release in the Releases view to use a .pfx file to digitally sign your release, InstallShield digitally signs the tag at build time. Note that the .NET Framework 2.0 or later must be installed on your build machine in order to sign a tag file.

Comment: The links are now dead :(

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the stuff below, but looking closer at your screenshot it looks like it's claiming certain files aren't in folders where it's looking... I don't think that has anything to do with installing the file to your system as your system isn't Vista, XP, AND Server 2008 (at least I would assume you aren't running three OS at the same time lol).  I could be wrong, but this sounds like an import problem... it looks like it's trying to import those files as files your user needs to install your program... you need to get those 3 installers and then import them (package them, whatever this program you are using does) as prerequisites.  That SHOULD solve the problem.

--------------Probably not applicable but if above is incorrect----------

Simple suggestions... unlikely, but my usual troubleshooting steps when all else fails.

Check your file paths.

Double check that you ARE installing the version for 64bit.

Your harddrive isn't full is it?

Turn off virus scanners.

Try installing in safe mode.

Run a virus scan (use something good like Malwarebytes).

Check the Windows error log.

If you downloaded it on a different device try downloading it on the computer you want to install it to.

Download the installer on a different device.

Run as Admin or from a new user account.

Change the folder you are running the installer out of... try running the installer right out of c:\

Install it through Windows Updates (I'm just assuming Win 7 has them, I avoid windows update).

Make sure you have all the .NET frameworks installed (I've seen odd things happen when you don't)

Run the installer on a different computer to make sure it works.

Found this through Google... http://winhlp.com/node/40 the bottom of the page shows some software that can contribute to this error... it may say 'server' but I'm sure that even if the computer isn't networked these can still cause the problem...